# How do I deliver an Excel 2007 VBA script?

Tags: vba, scripting, excel-2007

Once I've finished writing an Excel 2007 VBA script how to I deliver the Excel 2007 VBA script to the rest of the team members?

Is there a way to package an Excel 2007 VBA script so that it can be provided to other team members?

Thanks again for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deliver as an Excel add-in (no need for VSTO if you want, can be pure VBA). or you could export the module to a .bas file and send to your coworker.

Answer (score -1):

I afraid no.

If you want to deliver your script so that your teammate can reuse it easily, consider using [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx). In this way you can develop plugin for Excel, that other people can install and use.